# Do I need to wash every part three times during ablution?

Tags: wudu

Please someone tell me, should I wash every part three times during ablution such as mouth, nose, forearms etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer it would be best as it is sunna. But if you do it right once is sufficient!

Answer (score 1):

```
               In The Name of Allah, The Most Beneficent, The Most Merciful.
```

Washing body parts three times during ablution is not obligatory. Allah almighty, may he be glorified and exalted says regarding ablution (interpretation of the meaning):

> [5.6] O you who believe! when you rise up to prayer, wash your faces
> and your hands as far as the elbows, and wipe your heads and your feet
> to the ankles; and if you are under an obligation to perform a total
> ablution, then wash (yourselves) and if you are sick or on a journey,
> or one of you come from the privy, or you have touched the women, and
> you cannot find water, betake yourselves to pure earth and wipe your
> faces and your hands therewith, Allah does not desire to put on you
> any difficulty, but He wishes to purify you and that He may complete
> His favor on you, so that you may be grateful.

It is reported in Sahih al Bukhari that the prophet (peace be upon him) performed ablution by washing the body parts only once.

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas: The Prophet (ﷺ) performed ablution by washing the
> body parts only once.
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 186](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4)

However, it is recommended for Muslims to wash the body parts thrice because that is Sunnah. The hadith bellow describes how the prophet (peace be upon him) performed ablution :

> Narrated Amr: My father saw Amr bin Abi Hasan asking Abdullah bin
> Zaid about the ablution of the Prophet. Abdullah bin Zaid asked for
> earthenware pot containing water and in front of them performed
> ablution like that of the Prophet (ﷺ) . He poured water from the pot
> over his hand and washed his hands thrice and then he put his hands in
> the pot and rinsed his mouth and washed his nose by putting water in
> it and then blowing it out with three handfuls of water. Again he put
> his hand in the water and washed his face thrice and washed his
> forearms up to the elbows twice; and then put his hands in the water
> and then passed them over his head by bringing them to the front and
> then to the rear of the head once, and then he washed his feet up to
> the ankles.
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 240](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4)