# Last step of taking wudu

Tags: sunnah, wudu

I've already read this page full of information.

[Do I need to wash every part three times during ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30951/do-i-need-to-wash-every-part-three-times-during-ablution)

> My question is whether or not it is considered **sunnah** to wash your feeth thrice or just once?

This question originated from an argument between close relatives of mine. I hope I'll get an answer that sufficient enough inshallah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It was narrated from Ubayy bin Ka'b that:](https://sunnah.com/urn/1254190)

> The Messenger of Allah called for water and performed ablution once.
>   He said: "This is the minimum requirement of ablution' or he said:
>   'The ablution of one who, if he does not perform this ablution, Allah
>   will not accept his prayer." Then he performed ablution **washing each
>   part twice**, and he said: 'This is the ablution of one who, if he
>   performs it, Allah will give him two shares of reward." Then he
>   performed ablution **washing each part three times, and said: 'This is
>   my ablution** and the ablution of the Messengers who were sent before
>   me."

[Ibn Abbas narrated:](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/42)

> "The Prophet performed Wudu one time (for each limb)."

[Abu Hurairah narrated:](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/43)

> "The Prophet performed Wudu two time (for each limb)."

[Ali narrated that:](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/44)

> "The Prophet performed Wudu three times (for each limb)."

Means 1 time, 2 time and 3 time all are sunnah, but you want the triple reward then wash 3 times (from first hadith) and this is my WUDU and all the messengers before me, it's enough to use the 3 time one.

You already studied the quranic ayah in your question link, so no need to explain that part.